# Force bootstrap controls onto one line

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vue.js

[image]
With the group of three controls on the right, I can't figure out how to get them A) pulled to the right, and B) inline and nestled right next to each other, like the controls over on the left.

Here's the parent element for the right controls:

```
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <user-search></user-search>
            <batch-button></batch-button>
        </div>
```

Here's the `<user-search>` tag:

```
<div>
    <transition name="fade">
        <button v-if="userSearch" @click="undoSearch()" class="btn btn-default">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span>
        </button>
    </transition>
    <input type="text" @keyup.enter="findUser()" v-model="searchText" class="form-control" placeholder="find user"/>
</div>
```

And here's the `<batch-button>` tag:

```
<button class="btn btn-default" @click="show()" type="button">Batch Operations
    <span :class="{'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down': showForm, 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up': !showForm}"></span>
</button>
```

Adding text-right or pull-right does nothing or is counter-productive, from my experiments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing style, and missing code for user-search, but this should be enough for starting point:

```
 <div class="btnbox">
   <user-search></user-search>
    <button class="rbtn btn btn-default" @click="show()" type="button">Batch Operations <span :class="{'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down': showForm, 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up': !showForm}"></span></button>
  <button class="rbtn btn btn-default">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span>
    </button>
</div>
```

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/elance/52VtD/15650/

Comment: Have edited main post with more code and the current situation.

Comment: Very nice! One last thing - I want to actually join them together like the Bootstrap input-group classes - if you look at the left-hand controls in my screenshots above, they are perfectly joined and only have border-radiuses on the outer borders.